# Many to Many RelationShip in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, many-to-many

There are two tables in my database 
1. Doctor
2. Clinic

Here Doctor have one or more clinics and clinics can have one or more doctors..

So i want many to many relationship between both tables

So please tell me how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

With a third [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), where each record references a Doctor record and a Clinic record.